# Not able to ping from an Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have an Azure VM on a Virtual network. I tried the following:

```
ping google.com
```

and the connection timed out. I don't have a static IP address assigned to the VM. I tried enabling outbound ICMP but I am still not able to ping. Any particular reason why this may be happening?

Comment: What did Azure support say?

Comment: have not responded. any ideas?

Comment: Azure blocks all incoming/outgoing ICMP traffic for security reasons -- turning it on or off in your VM will have no effect. -- You'll need to use a different method to determine if the hosts you want are up or not.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an uncommon problem actually - it's entirely possible you're fine, just that it doesn't allow that ping. See this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity.aspx

Comment: i actually need a few domains to be accessible from my VM's so I tried pinging the domains. I tried psping and even that did not work.

Comment: you can also try using Powershell to test connectivity - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn372891(v=wps.630).aspx Make sure you have endpoints set up both in your internal firewall and in the portal - there's two places to check.

Comment: i tried it. did not work. the endpoints exist both within internal firewall and the portal

Comment: Try TestNet-Connection www.bing.com rather than google.com and see if it works that way.

Comment: bing works. but other domains such as google and the ones I want to don't work

Comment: This is normal for an Azure VM. You can probably access google and other domains just fine if you for example open a web browser and connect to them but ping will timeout. I tested this on a brand new VM just now, but it can still connect to Google.

Comment: i need to access a web service in a domain so i need to be able to access them. i am not able to access from the VM so I tried to ping and even that did not work. is there any way I can whitelist such domains. We can allow such access in AWS through a firewall rule in the portal. any way in Azure?

Comment: Yes, you can allow them via the firewall. It's just that Ping won't work - be sure when using PSPing that you are pinging at port 80, as I got an error just trying to ping the URL without specifying port 80. If that does not work for you, also try this http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/azure/azuresecurity.aspx?ID=11a814f2-ab1a-4a2e-9af2-5144848ad386  I will wager that your VM can already connect to Google.com if you RDP and open IE.

Comment: If all the domains you need access to are websites, you can just open a socket to them on port 80 and send a well formatted `GET` request and see if you get back an `HTTP 1.1/200 OK...` back...